# Jakarta EE CDI Event TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS event order is reverse

Tags: events, jakarta-ee, cdi

When annotation an observer method with `AFTER_SUCCESS`, the events are received in the reverse order they actually have been fired during the transaction.

Example pseudo code:

```
@Transactional
void test(){
    pushEvent.fire( new PushEvent(10) );
    pushEvent.fire( new PushEvent(20) );
    pushEvent.fire( new PushEvent(30) ); 
}
```

Observer:

```
void onPushEvent( @Observes( during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS ) PushEvent event ){
   System.out.println(event.getValue())
}
```

Unexpected, but observed result:

```
30
20
10
```

Can this be changed?

Comment: Observers in the AFTER_xxx phase are called out of sync (not asynchronously, i.e. in a different thread, just later). The spec does not say anything about the order of processing the events in this case, so my guess is that the order is implementation-specific and you cannot rely on it! I would consider placing the individual `PushEvents` in a `List` and firing an event that contains this list, to ensure the correct processing order.

Comment: Alternatively, e.g. if the events are not fired from a single place, you could have a synchronous observer gathering the individual `PushEvents` in a `List` (e.g. in a `@RequestScoped` bean). This is guaranteed to be called in the desired order. Then, somehow, this synchronous observer fires the event containing the list, to be processed in the AFTER_SUCCESS phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this in my project with a thread-local buffer of events which gets flushed on AFTER_SUCCESS and replays the events in the order they appeared in first place

```
ThreadLocal<List<PushEvent>> threadEventBufferHolder = ThreadLocal.withInitial( ArrayList::new );

void onPushEvent( @Observes( during = TransactionPhase.IN_PROGRESS ) PushEvent event ){
    threadEventBufferHolder.get().add( event );
}

void onPushEventFailure( @Observes( during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_FAILURE ) PushEvent event ){
    buffer.clear();
}

void onPushEventCommit( @Observes( during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS ) PushEvent event ){
    List<PushEvent> buffer = threadEventBufferHolder.get();
    buffer.forEach( this::doPrintlnValue );
    buffer.clear();
}
```

Unrelated code removed for easier reading